# Android specific MIME type list?

Tags: android, mime-types

I have been asked to add a "share" method to one of my Android applications which allows users to share by 1) Facebook 2) SMS and 3) Email

While researching, I have found that to allow users to select from "messaging" applications, I need to create the following Intent:

```
    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
    messageIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    // title and content set elsewhere...
```

This *kind of* works, although I am also given email clients in my list...

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a list somewhere of the Android specific MIME types that are available for us to use? The "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" seemed pulled out of thin air to me from the example I found.
2. Is there the proper way to get ONLY messaging clients (ie. not mail clients) - or is that pretty much impossible to do in Android.

Disclaimer: The above code snippet was found from another SO post. Perhaps it is just me failing at Google - but I cannot seem to find any documentation on the legit Android developer site which listed out that this was the correct way to do this, or what my options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been asked to add a "share" method to one of my Android applications which allows users to share by 1) Facebook 2) SMS and 3) Email

Please allow the users to [share how the users want](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html), which may or may not be via those means.

> I have found that to allow users to select from "messaging" applications, I need to create the following Intent

No, that allows users to share via any application that happens to support that undocumented and unsupported MIME type. Not every "messaging" application will necessarily support that MIME type, and applications that are not "messaging" applications are welcome to support that MIME type.

> Is there a list somewhere of the Android specific MIME types that are available for us to use?

Not really, as generally they are undocumented or under-documented (e.g., the constant shows up somewhere without explanation).

> The "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" seemed pulled out of thin air to me from the example I found.

It probably came from [the Android source code](http://source.android.com).

> Is there the proper way to get ONLY messaging clients (ie. not mail clients) - or is that pretty much impossible to do in Android.

There are ~7 billion people on the planet. Each of them is welcome to have a different idea of what a "messaging client" is, what a "mail client" is, etc. Those are descriptive marketing terms, not technical definitions.

`ACTION_SEND` is for sharing content via MIME type. Any application can offer to support `ACTION_SEND` for any given MIME type, as the developers of any application can write what they want. Whether any given application is a "messaging client", "mail client", or something else is up to the end user. You have no means of reading the minds of users, nor do you have any legal means to prevent other programmers from writing what they want.

Now, there are various script-kiddie hacks for limiting the share list to certain *apps*, by application ID (a.k.a., package name). However, while there is only one Facebook (though I seem to recall they have a few apps), there are many SMS and email apps, and it would be difficult, if not impossible, for you to come up with a list of all of them, let alone maintain that list over time.

My **strong** recommendation is to format your content usefully, and allow the users to share that content using the apps that they wish.

Comment: That was kind of what my gut was telling me. Unfortunately the features / UI are being given to me from "higher up" (ie. project managers / designers). I will tell them that this is not the Android way to go and see what they say.